# Cordova: How to add existing custom plugin 2.3 into project 3.0

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0, cordova-3

I am new to PhoneGap development. I have a custom plugin created in version 2.3 and I have to use in version 3.0.

I tried to use using below command but could not succeeded:
cordova plugin add /Desktop/SuperUnicorn-master

Answer (score 0):

You can check on phonegap build if the plugin doesn't already exist in a newer version https://build.phonegap.com/plugins (most of the plugins listed there are updated for phonegap 3)

Otherwise you will have to convert the plugin yourself. For android it would be :

- convert the code from the 2.3 syntax to the 2.7+ syntax : http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.fr/2013/06/why-dont-my-plugins-work-in-phonegap.html
- add the files manually in platforms/android/... if you do not want to use the CLI
- or create a plugin.xml to be able to install the plugin using the CLI. For that I suggest you read the [Phonegap plugin specification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification) and then have a look at existing plugins to have different samples.

Comment: The plugin is developed in IOS platform. How do we added in existing project? Where to put complete project folder into existing project. Both, plugin and project has same structure. The basic difference is plugin is developed in 2.3 and project is developed in 3.0.